# Sidebar that expands on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to animate a sidebar with javascript that shows category icons by default and shows the category words on hover. The closest example I can think of is this one: http://piccsy.com/.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm still getting the hang of javascript.

Comment: What have you attempted?...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just with CSS using  `.myclass:hover` you'd have to check compatibility with older browsers because you will have to use css transition to animate.  This is a good starting point [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Or if you want to use javascript I'd recommend using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com)'s `mouseover()` event function.  when this event is triggered you can then animate the side nav.

Good luck